# In Webtrends, what browser is "Mozilla <Version Unknown>"?

Tags: analytics, user-agent

I am getting a ton of visits from a browser that is showing up in my Webtrends stats as "Mozilla" with version listed as "Version Unknown." It's almost 14% of my page views. This is separate from Firefox. Does anyone know what browser this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had similar issues with this in the past. From what I've read, there is a big possibility that it is actually IE 11 (really, it comes down to how Webtrends interprets it). This is because IE recently made changes to its User Agent. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Oh actually this would make sense, because I just noticed IE 11 isn't showing up at all! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how linking Mozilla to IE 11 makes sense, but it definitely clears things up.

Comment: @Mast: all major browsers have been pretending that they're Mozilla/Netscape for the last decade because of User Agent sniffings. Shows you how useful User-Agent is... not.